# Node JS and node-firebird multiple queries in one transaction

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have tried now in two days without any good result.

```
transaction.query("INSERT INTO INVOICE (INVOICE_NO,INVOICE_NO_TMP,UNIT_TYPE,UNIT_TYPE_TEXT,TAX_PERCENT,QTY,SALE_PRICE,SERIALNUMBER,DISCOUNT,PARTNO,PARTNO_ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING ID",array, function(err, result) {
      if (err){
        res.end(err.toString());
        transaction.rollback();
        db.detach();
        return result;                
      }
     })
```

And when i do a new query, it only start a new transaction, and i cannot rollback or commit. I only get this message:
invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)

How do i keep the first transaction every time i do a new query?
The db.transaction is starting a transaction it seems, but when running queries in it it only start new ones.

```
db.transaction(Firebird.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITED, await async  function(err,transaction) {
});
```

i want it like this:

```
transaction.query("INSERT INTO INVOICE (INVOICE_NO,INVOICE_NO_TMP,UNIT_TYPE,UNIT_TYPE_TEXT,TAX_PERCENT,QTY,SALE_PRICE,SERIALNUMBER,DISCOUNT,PARTNO,PARTNO_ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING ID",array, function(err, result) {
  if (err){
    res.end(err.toString());
    transaction.rollback();
    db.detach();
    return result;                
  }
 })
transaction.query("INSERT INTO INVOICE (INVOICE_NO,INVOICE_NO_TMP,UNIT_TYPE,UNIT_TYPE_TEXT,TAX_PERCENT,QTY,SALE_PRICE,SERIALNUMBER,DISCOUNT,PARTNO,PARTNO_ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING ID",array, function(err, result) {
  if (err){
    res.end(err.toString());
    transaction.rollback();
    db.detach();
    return result;                
  }
 })
 transaction.commit(function(err) {
   if (err)
     transaction.rollback();
   else
     db.detach();
 });
```

With the same transaction.
I tried an tried, but without success.
I see that for mySQL it is easy, but not in node-firebird.
I looked at the test index in github, This have transactions and multiple inserts, but this is totally wrong. This test do not show how to use the same transaction outside the block of code, so it is not useful info. It do not work with going through an array of list and doing the inserts.
It's only for node-firebird that i can't find this info.
Tried to search for examples, but it don't exists.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

I use promise and await. I use this in a loop for iterating through all new row items.
One problem with this was something strange.
When the insert SQL use RETURNING ID, it Crash on every second row. I used a whole day figure this out.
RETURNING command in the SQL don't work good with several inserts in the same transaction. But it works good without transaction.
A bug in node-firebird or Firebird engine.
I had to do it in another way. I first do a manual select from a procedure that results in a new highest row id + 1. And then i just do rowID++ each time i insert.

This is my solution:

```
  var addItems= async function (i,params,ID){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Important for waiting for the result
      var params2=[];
      params2.push(rowID);
      params2=params2.concat(params); 
        transaction.query("INSERT INTO INVOICE (ID, INVOICE_NO,INVOICE_NO_TMP,UNIT_TYPE,UNIT_TYPE_TEXT,TAX_PERCENT,QTY,SALE_PRICE,SERIALNUMBER,DISCOUNT,PARTNO,PARTNO_ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ",params2,  function(err, result) {
            if (err){
                transaction.rollback();
                db.detach();
                reject(err.toString());
                return false;
            }
          resolve(true);    
        });
    });
  }
```

And i call it with this, in the loop:

```
var result=await addItems(i,params,invoice.head[0].INVOICE_NO_TMP)                      
  if (result==true){
    rowID++;
  }else{
    transaction.rollback();
    reject(result.toString());
    break;
    return false;
  }
```

And after the loop i do:

```
  transaction.commit(function(err) {
      if (err){
        reject(err.toString());
        transaction.rollback();
        db.detach();
        return false;
      }
    db.detach();
  });
```

And, in the end, i finish with:

```
var result=await updateFromList();  
res.end(result);
```

The updateFromList function is that function that start the insert or update of all rows.

It was not easy to create this when i didn't realize that RETURNING ID was crashing it all. It took allot of testing to get to it, and realize that it was crashing it all.

It works good now.
It was important to be able to use transaction, because without it, the data is very unstable.